# Issues patching FormArrays values with data from server in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular form where a user fills in the form and selects multiple books via checkboxes and send the data to the server. The user can later edit the form again. When a user wants to edit the form, the form must be shown to the user pre-filled with the previous data the user has already submitted.

The problem I am having now is how to pre-filled the checkboxes with the values the user has already submitted. There are five checkboxes and the user can select two. When he wants to edit the data later, i want to pre-select the checkboxes he has selected before.

### Current problem

When I run my code, the checkboxes appears and vanishes instantly within a second. Because of that am not able to see whether they are checked or not.

The following is a stripdown of my code so that you can understand the problem.

**// Model Interface**

```
export interface BooksModel {
  books?: Array<any>;
}


export class AdviesHandicapComponent implements OnInit {
   private sub: any;
   service: DataService;
   books = new FormArray([]);
   booksModel: BooksModel;
   booksForm: FormGroup;

 booksOptions = [
   {id: 1, book: 'Biology'},
    {id: 2, book: 'Physics'},
    {id: 3, book: 'Chemistry'},
    {id: 4, book: 'Maths'},
    {id: 6, book: 'None of the above'}
  ];

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.service = new DataService();

       this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
       const tok = params['tok'];
       if (tok) {
         const results = this.service.getBooks();
         booksModel = results.reg;
         patchBooksForm();
       }
    });

   const booksFormControls = this.booksOptions.map(book => new FormControl(false));
    this.books = new FormArray(booksFormControls);
    this.booksForm = this.fb.group({
      books: this.books,
    });
   }

   patchBooks(ind: string[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.books.controls.length; i++) {
      for (const d of ind) {
        if (this.booksOptions[i].book === d) {
          this.books.controls[i].patchValue(true);
        }
      }
    }
  }

patchBooksForm(): void {
    patchBooks(this.booksModel.books); // I call this method here to patch the formarray values
    this.booksForm.patchValue({
    books: this.books.controls
    });
  }

}
```

### Data from server

The user may have selected the following books. So when he comes back later I want these books to be selected before he starts editing the form.**

```
export class DataService {
     getBooks() {
       return  {"reg":{"books":["Biology","Maths"]}};
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, your untouched form looks like:

```ts
{
  "books": [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false
  ]
}
```

To achieve the same when patching, you are now having issues, that you are patching it twice, first time with correct values in your `for` loop in `patchBooks()`, second time patching it with the books controls in `patchBooksForm()`. You should remove those lines:

```ts
// remove
// this.booksForm.patchValue({
//   books: this.books.controls
// });
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpvpvj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Just a remark, does it make sense to not having any identifier in the formarray, now there's just a bunch of falses and trues, but that is of course up to you :) Also another remark, not related, you should **inject** your service in the constructor, and not call: `this.service = new DataService();`.